# How does list I/O writev internally work?

Tags: c, io, posix

The `writev` function takes an array of struct iovec as input argument

`writev(int fd, const struct iovec *iov, int iovcnt);`

The input is a list of memory buffers that need to be written to a file (say). What I want to know is:

Does writev internally do this:

`for (each element in iov)
    write(element)`

such that every element of `iov` is written to file in a separate I/O call? Or does `writev` write everything to file in a *single* I/O call?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per the standards, the for loop you mentioned is not a valid implementation of `writev`, for several reasons:

1. The loop could fail to finish writing one iov before proceeding to the next, in the event of a short write - but this could be worked around by making the loop more elaborate.
2. The loop could have incorrect behavior with respect to atomicity for pipes: if the total write length is smaller than `PIPE_BUF`, the pipe write is required to be atomic, but the loop would break the atomicity requirement. This issue cannot be worked around except by moving all the iov entries into a single buffer before writing when the total length is at most `PIPE_BUF`.
3. The loop might have cases where it could result in blocking, where the single `writev` call would be required to perform a partial write without blocking. As far as I know, this issue would be impossible to work around in the general case.
4. Possibly other reasons I haven't thought of.

I'm not sure about point #3, but it definitely exists in the opposite direction, when reading. Calling `read` in a loop could block if a terminal has some data (shorter than the total iov length) available followed by an EOF indicator; calling `readv` **should** return immediately with a partial read in this case. However, due to a bug in Linux, `readv` on terminals is actually implemented as a `read` loop in kernelspace, and it does exhibit this blocking bug. I had to work around this bug in implementing musl's stdio:

http://git.etalabs.net/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=musl;a=commit;h=2cff36a84f268c09f4c9dc5a1340652c8e298dc0

To answer the last part of your question:

> Or does `writev` write everything to file in a single I/O call?

In all cases, a conformant `writev` implementation will be a single syscall. Getting down to how it's implemented on Linux: for ordinary files and for most devices, the underlying file driver has methods that implement iov-style io directly, without any sort of internal loop. But the terminal driver on Linux is highly outdated and lacks the modern io methods, causing the kernel to fallback to a write/read loop for `writev`/`readv` when operating on a terminal.

Comment: I dont understand the last line "when operating on a terminal". Also, where exactly in the linux src do you check the writev implementation?

Comment: "When operating on a terminal" means when the file descriptor refers to a terminal device. As for where in the source, http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.2.6/fs/read_write.c#L809

Answer (score 4):

The direct way to know how code works is read the source code.

see http://www.oschina.net/code/explore/glibc-2.9/sysdeps/posix/writev.c

It simplely alloca() or malloc() a buffer, copy all vectors into it, and call write() once.

That how it works. Nothing mysterious.

Comment: That's glibc writev, not linux kernel writev.

Answer (score 3):

```
Or does writev write everything to file in a single I/O call?
```

I'm afarid not everything, though sys_writev try its best to write everything in a single  call. it's depends on vfs's implement, if the vfs doesn't give an implement of writev, then kenerl will call vfs' write() in a loop. it's better to check the return value of writev/readv to see how many bytes wrotten as you do in write().

you can find the code of writev in kernel, fs/read_write.c:do_readv_writev.